# ¿Por qué el evento click se dispara solo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet

Estoy haciendo una APP que pilla coordenadas de lugares de una base de datos y mediante elementos `marker` saco esos puntos a un mapa. Después, para que cada `marker` me lleve a una página hecha diatónicamente con los datos de ese sitio en cuestión. Para ello, hice un evento `onclick` de la siguiente manera:

```
for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){
    marcador1=L.marker([data[0][i].latitud, data[0][i].longitud], {title: data[0][i].nombre, 
    alt: data[0][i].nombre}).on('click', irSitio(data[0][i].id)).addTo(map1); 
}
```

Todo esto está dentro del `succes` de una función `ajax` que coge todos los datos que se ven por ahí: `data[0][i].nombre`..... Si os fijáis, hay un evento `onClick`, que llama a una función con un parámetro (el id del sitio).
Después hago la función a la que llama el evento de la siguiente manera.

```
function irSitio(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'sitioBusca.php',
        data:{
            "idSitio":id
        },
        success:
        function() {
            $(location).attr('href','sitio.php');
        }
    });
}
```

Esta función, lo único que hace, es ir a un archivo php `sitioBusca.php` para, una vez en él, crear una sesión, para después, si todo sale bien, con la función del `success`, redirigir a otra página donde ya puedo usar el id guardado en la sesión para sacar el resto de los datos del sitio y usarlos. 
La movida es que el evento click se dispara solo y al cargar la página se va automáticamente a la otra página a la que redirecciona la función del `success` en vez de esperar a dispararse cuando haces click en el `marker`.
Alguna idea de lo que puedo estar haciendo mal?
Gracias y saludos a todos.

Comment: No sé por qué motivo estás asignando un evento `onClick` dentro del `for`. Ahí solamente deberías crear/modificar tus elementos. El evento `onClick` va aparte, indicándole a qué elementos va ligado, identificándolos por su `id`, por su clase, por el tipo de elemento u otro. Es en teoría algo así como una función que es llamada cuando alguno de esos elementos es clickeado. Por el contrario, aquí parece que llamas al evento dentro del bucle: `for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){  ... data[0][i].nombre}).on('click', irSitio(data[0][i].id)).addTo(map1);`

Comment: No sé, lo puse para que cada marker que se creara con el bucle, tuviera su propio evento con la función con el id de cada uno como parámetro, porque no supe encontrar la forma de ponerle atributos, como una clase, id o un value para poder hacerlo de otra forma.

Comment: Precisamente eso es lo que tienes que hacer, ponerle un atributo, por ejemplo una clase, y luego alcanzar los elementos de esa clase y asignarle el *listener*. No puedes llamar un `onClick` dentro del bucle, por eso se está disparando como es lógico.

Comment: Pero si el evento es un onclick... como es que se dispara solo, si nadie está haciendo click? Pensaba que funcionaba como cuando creas un botón y le pones un evento onclick: hasta que no pulsas el botón no se dispara el evento. Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero es que soy novato. Esto es para el proyecto de clase.

Comment: Tengo otra versión hecha que lleva un popup en cada marker, y ahí sí que pude ponerle un botón dentro del popup con sus atributos y hacerlo como tú dices, pero la verdad es que no me mola mucho con los popups esos... si supieras decirme una forma de poner atributos a los marker... te estaría enormemente agradecido. :)

Comment: El problema es que yo no he trabajado con marker y tu código no me parece convencional, por eso no me he atrevido a darte una respuesta, esperando que alguien que trabaje con eso pueda orientarte mejor. ¿Esos marker de que son, de Google Maps o algo así?

Comment: Está hecho con Leaflet, que es una librería opensource para trabajar con mapas. Dicen que tiene buena documentación, pero yo debo ser muy tordo, que no consigo solucionarlo. A ver si como tú dices, aparece alguien que trabaje con esta librería y me pueda echar un cable. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que la estás invocando cuando se la pasas al onclick acá

on('click', irSitio(data[0][i].id))

Lo que puedes hacer es declarar un closure para que sea el evento el que llame tu función

```
  function irSitio(id) { 
              return function (event){
              $.ajax({ 
              type: 'get', url: 'sitioBusca.php', data:{ "idSitio":id },
     success: function() { 
    $(location).attr('href','sitio.php');
     }
     });
} }
```

Así cuando lo llames en tu bucle  vas a devolver una función que es lo que espera el onclick